# kivy updating progess bar while app is processing

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i would like to have a progress bar in my app while the programme is running un the background but since the process takes about 15 seconds i always get app not responding until it finishes processing without updating the progress bar values

```
class Processing(Screen):
    model_text=model_text_eng
    model_audio=model_audio_eng
    text=""
    final_image=[]
    res_audio={}
    res_text={}

    def image_processing(self,path):
        files = glob.glob('C:/Users/BOX/Downloads/M2 ESE/programme/image extract/*')
        for f in files:
                os.remove(f)

        vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
        success,images = vidcap.read()
        count = 0
        while success:
            cv2.imwrite("image extract/frame%d.jpg" % count, images)     # save frame as JPEG file      
            success,images = vidcap.read()
            count += 1
        extracted= os.listdir("image extract/")
        
        
        repeat=[]
        count2=0
        for file in extracted:
            loc=f"image extract/frame{count2}.jpg"
            image1 = face_recognition.load_image_file("image extract/"+file)
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image1)
            width, height =0,0
            for face_location in face_locations:
                top, right, bottom, left = face_location
                face_image = image1[top+20:bottom+20, left+20:right+20]
                pil_image = Image2.fromarray(face_image)
                if (pil_image.size[0]*pil_image.size[1]>width*height):
                    width, height = pil_image.size
                    pil_image.save(loc)

            img = image.load_img(loc, target_size=(48, 48),color_mode='grayscale')
            img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
            img_batch = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)

            predict_image=model_image.predict(img_batch)
            res = {k:v for k, v in zip(classes, predict_image[0]*100)}
            repeat.append(res)
            count2+=1
        
        self.manager.ids.processing.final_imge = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: dict((k, v + y[k]) for k, v in x.items()), repeat)

    def on_enter(self):
    self.image_processing(self.manager.ids.main.filename)
    self.ids.progress_bar.value=25
    self.extract_text_audio(self.manager.ids.main.filename)
    self.ids.progress_bar.value=50
    self.audio_processing(self.manager.ids.main.filename)
    self.ids.progress_bar.value=75
    self.text_processing()
    self.ids.progress_bar.value=100
    self.manager.current = 'Results'
```

Comment: Use `thread` for non kivy processes and return custom widget to show user to wait for process if you don't want to let'em make any operation.

Comment: yes! that worked. i had previously tried with multiprocessing but that didn't work, multithreading works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multithreading works (thanks to @320V)

```
class Processing(Screen):
    model_text=model_text_eng
    model_audio=model_audio_eng
    text=""
    final_image=[]
    res_audio={}
    res_text={}
    data= np.array([])
    sample_rate=0

    def progess(self):
            mustend = time.time() + 60
            while time.time() < mustend:
                if self.manager.ids.processing.final_image != [] and self.manager.ids.processing.text=="":
                    self.ids.progress_bar.value=25
                if self.manager.ids.processing.text!="" and self.manager.ids.processing.final_image != []:
                    self.ids.progress_bar.value=50
                if self.manager.ids.processing.res_audio!={} and self.manager.ids.processing.text!="":
                    self.ids.progress_bar.value=75
                if self.manager.ids.processing.res_text!={} and self.manager.ids.processing.res_audio!={}:
                    self.ids.progress_bar.value=100
                    self.manager.current = 'Results'
                time.sleep(1)
            return False
            

        def image_processing(self,path):
            files = glob.glob('C:/Users/BOX/Downloads/M2 ESE/programme/image extract/*')
            for f in files:
                os.remove(f)

            vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
            success,images = vidcap.read()
            count = 0
            while success:
                cv2.imwrite("image extract/frame%d.jpg" % count, images)     # save frame as JPEG file      
                success,images = vidcap.read()
                count += 1
            extracted= os.listdir("image extract/")
            
            
            repeat=[]
            count2=0
            for file in extracted:
                loc=f"image extract/frame{count2}.jpg"
                image1 = face_recognition.load_image_file("image extract/"+file)
                face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image1)
                width, height =0,0
                for face_location in face_locations:
                    top, right, bottom, left = face_location
                    face_image = image1[top+20:bottom+20, left+20:right+20]
                    pil_image = Image2.fromarray(face_image)
                    if (pil_image.size[0]*pil_image.size[1]>width*height):
                        width, height = pil_image.size
                        pil_image.save(loc)

                img = image.load_img(loc, target_size=(48, 48),color_mode='grayscale')
                img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
                img_batch = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)

                predict_image=model_image.predict(img_batch)
                res = {k:v for k, v in zip(classes, predict_image[0]*100)}
                repeat.append(res)
                count2+=1
            
            self.manager.ids.processing.final_image = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: dict((k, v + y[k]) for k, v in x.items()), repeat)

        def on_enter(self):
            t1=Thread(target=self.image_processing)
            t2=Thread(target=self.progess)
            t1.start()
            t2.start()
```